# Not able to connect Oracle database from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, oracle11g, 32bit-64bit

I'm running:

- Win 10 64 Bit
- Oracle Client 11.2 64 Bit
- Visual Studio 2015 Professional Edition.

Getting below error. Please help us how to change the mode in Visual Studio to use 64 bit Oracle Client.

Just to add, Before installing 64 bit client, I had 32 bit client installed and even then I was not able to connect Oracle from VS.

[image]

Comment: What's your projects build setting? x86, x64, AnyCPU?

Comment: @Jessehouwing, Only option available is AnyCPU so using that option

Comment: You can add other build types through the solution configuration manager, but with any cpu you're not sure which is used at startup, in your case, best force it to be either x64 or x86.